# Shariff-Sharing: Change URL / Title on the fly

Tags: javascript

I'm using shariff-sharing for a site to be shared in several networks.
Now i want to change the title and url on user interaction.
Is there any possible way to do so? 
i just came to the point that it would be possible to add URL Parameters which could be processed for different titles but that's not very fancy.

Comment: Do you want to change the `Title` of page, if yes than simply grab this tag name `var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]` and apply function.

Comment: Thank you, but that does not affect shariff-sharing. It still uses the old title.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, my solution is the following:

after the URLs changing i call the following function:

```
function setDataAttributes() {
   //updateDataAttributes just refreshs the global variable for productImg and productUrl 
   updateDataAttributes();
    $('.shariff').each(function() {
        // new instance with new options
        this.shariff = new Shariff(this,{
            mediaUrl: productImg,
            url: productUrl
        });
    });
}
```

i listen on the click event for the ".shariff-button" and then i call my setDataAttributes, after that my link is changed.